# What is a four-wind game called in Japanese mahjong?

Tags: mahjong, riichi-mahjong

In Japanese mahjong generally the longest game most people play is a hanchan (半荘), where the *han* part (半) implies that it's "half" of something, presumably a full four-wind game with 16 hands.

But is there a name for a four-wind game in Japanese? I can't find a reference for it anywhere if it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C), the word is イーチャン, or 一荘 in kanji - read as iichan (although it's unusualy in that it appears to be written in katakana, which I'm guessing could mean that it's a fairly new loanword from Chinese?). There's a JMdictDB entry on it [here](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&disp=ed&e=1909377).